# Grails mappedBy

Tags: grails

I am doing a simple program in Grails and am having problems with the many to many relationships. I have an Airport class:

```
class Airport 
{
   static hasMany = [outgoingFlights:Flight, incomingFlights:Flight]
   static mappedBy = [outgoingFlights:'departureAirport', 
                      incomingFlights:'arrivalAirport']
}
```

and a Flight class:

```
class Flight
{
   Airport departureAirport
   Airport arrivalAirport
}
```

for some reason it gives me a very long and odd error message for mappedBy. Is there something wrong with the mappedBy code or do I need to do something else as well? Thanks.

Comment: Can you include the error here?

Comment: Do you have the correct package name set in both classes? I copied and pasted you code and it seems to work fine for me...

Comment: No signature of method: trip_planner.Airline.notes() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[maxSize:1500]] is the simple version for the error message. And both are set in the same package

Comment: the problem is not in that mapping but elsewhere. more source code and fullstack trace needed

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
class Flight
{
   static belongsTo = [departureAirport: Airport, arrivalAirport: Airport ]
   Airport departureAirport
   Airport arrivalAirport
}
```

Recreate your database.